# How to find the location of my Grunt package via CLI command?

Tags: command-line, 13.04, locate, grunt

I am trying to find the location of my grunt package, but when I run:

```
where grunt
```

I get the following error message:

```
No command 'where' found, did you mean:
Command 'gwhere' from package 'gwhere' (universe)
where: command not found
```

What is the correct command/syntax?

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful, if yes, please mark the appropriate as accepted by clicking on the check mark besides the answer?

Answer (score 7):

If you are searching for information about `grunt`.Run

```
whereis grunt
```

Or

```
whatis grunt
```

Or

```
which grunt
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not `where` but `which`. So

```
which grunt
```

will tell you the location of the binary.

Answer (score 2):

The command to locate the binary package is `which` and the command to locate the binary and manual packages is `whereis`. So `which ls` would give

```
/bin/ls
```

and `whereis ls` would give

```
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

where the first argument `/bin/ls` is the binary file and `/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz` is the manual page.